# Using pagination with images

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, pagination

Alright so, a friend and I are trying to build a website. It gets pictures from two directories, and shows them in chronological order (the image name is a timestamp). We make a JSON object using PHP and have the following code:

```
<?php

$files = array();

$dir = opendir('./dir1');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $files[] = array('name'=>($file), 'tag'=>"tag1");

}

$dir = opendir('./dir2');
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
        continue;
    }

    $files[] = array('name'=>($file), 'tag'=>"tag2");

}

usort($files,function($b,$a) {return strnatcasecmp($a['name'],$b['name']);});

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($files);

?>
```

We have a javascript file that looks like this:

```
function PictureController2($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('pictest.php').success(function(data) {
        $scope.pictures = data;
    });

};
```

And it is handled by HTML to create a page that shows the images w/ a thumbnail and image name in a grid. Unfortunately, it is all on one page, and there eventually will be a large number of images, so we were looking into pagination. We found this nifty code on jfiddle from another thread, http://jsfiddle.net/2ZzZB/56/, but are having trouble integrating our code into that one. We're both new to AngularJS so we're not sure how to properly combine our program with theirs.

Comment: Can you post your views?  That's where the actually page limiting is happening in the fiddle you posted.

Comment: Please post what your JSON response looks like and what your view looks like

Comment: @EliteOctagon: [{"name":"img_2014-04-26_23-00-25.jpg","tag":"tag1"}, ...] is what our JSON file is, where tag1 can be 1 or 2.

Comment: ok, an array of objects should work for the answer I gave below. Updated my answer

Comment: Do post what your current HTML looks like.

Comment: Also, have you tried http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ it's another download, but it has a bunch of directives, like pagination that can take care or carousel which can take care of things you need

Comment: @jonathanpglick: currently our view is:
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <a href="http://localhost/pics/{{picture.tag}}/{{picture.name}}"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://localhost/pics/{{picture.tag}}/{{picture.name}}" alt=""></a>
      <a href="http://localhost/pics/{{picture.tag}}/{{picture.name}}"><center>{{picture.name}}</center></a>
       </div>

Comment: there should be a slash between pics and picture.tag like so::: pics/{{picture.tag}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given:

```
$http.get('pictest.php').success(function(response) { 
    // this returns a promise, so you need to check the data
    $scope.pictures = response.data;
});
```

lets say your JSON returned is something like this:

```
$scope.pictures= {one: "/local/myimg1.jpg", two: "/local/someOther.jpg"}; // returned from service
```

then you can create a view which uses this $scope data

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in pictures"> <!-- repeat a div of pictures; key from above example would be 'one' and 'two'-->
    <!-- here, ng-src uses the value from the JSON, the web address, and if it can't find that (an error), then defaults to a different address  -->
    <img height=100 width=200 ng-src="value" onerror="this.src = 'images/ImageNotAvailable.png';"/> 
</div>
```

now to add pagination, you have a few options, you can use ng-show, ng-hide, ng-if and filters to limit what is shown, or using the filter from the link you provided:

```
app.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
        start = +start; //parse to int
        return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

you can change the ng-repeat and div to the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in pictures | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"">
    <img height=100 width=200 ng-src="value" onerror="this.src = 'images/ImageNotAvailable.png';"/> 
</div>
```

where $scope.currentPage and $scope.pageSize are defined in your controller as integers

---

Update

```
<div ng-repeat="picture in pictures | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"">
    <img height=100 width=200 ng-src="picture.name"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Alright so we're trying to use your solution, and we get a nice little page number down at the bottom, but when we add " | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize"" to our ng-repeat, the images stop displaying. Thanks for the help so far, much appreciated.

Comment: Oh and, after some further tests, we're figuring that the startFrom:currentPage*pageSize is for whatever reason causing the problem. When we leave it out, we get 10 images on the page, but with it it doesn't show anything.